# Can I use SA_SIGINFO flag to get SIGKILL information?

Tags: linux, process, signals

I have a process mysteriously gets killed, likely by SIGKILL. So I would like to know who sent this SIGKILL to my process, be it kernel or other user process. There're questions on SO about getting to know SIGTERM sender PID, but apparently SIGKILL cannot be handled by process?

So if this doesn't work, how can I get to know who sent the SIGKILL to my process? Thank you guys.

PS: systap is not the best option for me because I'm working on an embedded device.

Answer (score 1):

gdb the process. You can individually configure which signals should cause process to pause. (and also add breakpoint to exit and _exit)